# How to insert using different table based on condition in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am merging data in one table from tables of 2 database. Structure is as per below:

> **Table in new Database** :
>
> User Table : {UserName,Email}
>
> **Table in Database1** :
>
> User Table : {UserName,Email,LastLogin}
>
> **Table in Database2** :
>
> User Table : {UserName,Email,LastLogin}

Now i need to write query that if Email address are same in 2 tables from database 1 and database2 then we need to insert record where LastLogin is latest.

Can someone suggest over this.

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result (all as well formatted text.) Also show us your current query attempt!

Comment: Tagged with `sql-server` based on the comment to the first answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are in need of this.. :)

Try modifying it accordingly..

```
declare @Email_1 nvarchar(100),@Email_2 nvarchar(100),@UserName nvarchar(100),@Lastlogin_1 datetime,@Lastlogin_2 datetime,@loop int=0
use [Database1]
while @loop != (select count(Distinct Email) from [User Table])
BEGIN
use [Database1]
set @Email_1 = (select Distinct Email from [User Table] order by email asc offset @loop rows fetch next 1 rows only)
set @LastLogin_1 = (select top 1 max(LastLogin) from [User Table] where email=@Email_1)

use [Database2]
set @Email_2 = (select top 1 Email from [User Table]  where Email like '%@Email_1%')
set @LastLogin_2 = (select top 1 max(LastLogin) from [User Table] where email=@Email_2)

if @email_1=@email_2
BEGIN
if @LastLogin_1>@LastLogin_2
BEGIN
use [Database_1]
set @username = (select top 1 Username from [user table] where email=@email_1 and lastlogin=@Lastlogin_1)
use [New Database]
insert into [User Table]
select @username,@email_1
END
else if @LastLogin_1<@LastLogin_2
BEGIN
use [Database_2]
set @username = (select top 1 Username from [user table] where email=@email_2 and lastlogin=@Lastlogin_2)
use [New Database]
insert into [User Table]
select @username,@email_1
use [Database1]
END
END
set @loop=@loop+1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

My following code are assuming all tables are in one database, this is more for demo convenience purpose. In real world, when you have tables in different databases, then you need to use 3-part naming convention, i.e.

```
[DB].[Schema].[Table]
```

Also I am testing in sql server environment.

```
use tempdb 
drop table dbo.merge_tbl, dbo.t1, dbo.t2;
create table dbo.merge_tbl (username varchar(30), email varchar(30));

create table dbo.t1 (username varchar(30), email varchar(30), lastlogin datetime)
create table dbo.t2 (username varchar(30), email varchar(30), lastlogin datetime)
go
-- insert a few records to tables
insert into dbo.t1 (username, email, lastlogin)
values ('james1', 'j@a.com', '20161001'), ('jenny1', 'j2@b.com', '20161002'), ('jeffrey1', 'j3@c.com', '20150101')

insert into dbo.t2(username, email, lastlogin)
values ('james2', 'j@a.com', '20161006'), ('jenny2', 'j2@b.com', '20151002'), ('jeffrey2', 'j4@c.com', '20170101')
go

-- this is the insert statement
insert into dbo.merge_tbl (username, email)
select case when t1.lastlogin >= t2.lastlogin then t1.username else t2.username end
,   case when t1.lastlogin >= t2.lastlogin then t1.email else t2.email end 
from dbo.t1 
inner join dbo.t2
on t1.email = t2.email;
go

-- check result
select * from dbo.merge_tbl
```

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: I used same logic but i have more than 15 column in my table so should i check each field in case or do we have any way by which we can check condition once and then retrieve complete record

Comment: I have existing 2 databases which are on sql server. in User table have almost 15 column so do we have any way which we can check once and then insert all column .

Answer (score 0):

follow 3 part naming convention(`[Database Name].[Schema].[Table name]`) while accessing your table in different database. Also  there may be multiple log in entries for a single user in the table `[User Table]` ,so use grouping function in such scenario.

If you are using `SQL Server`,use the below script for achieving the result.

```
INSERT INTO [New Database].dbo.[User Table] (UserName,Email)
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(a.LastLogin)>=MAX(b.LastLogin) THEN a.[UserName] ELSE b.[UserName] END [UserName],a.Email
FROM Database1.dbo.[User Table] a
 JOIN  Database2.dbo.[User Table] b
   ON a.Email=b.Email
GROUP BY a.[UserName],b.[UserName],a.Email
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the three database db0, db1 and db2. For merging data in database db0 run the following query:

```
insert into db0.user('name','email')
select name, email from (
select db1.name,db1.email,
case 
  when db1.user.lastlogin >= db2.user.lastlogin 
  then db1.user.lastlogin
  else db2.user.lastlogin
end as lastlogin
from db1.user,db2.user
where db1.user.email = db2.user.email ) as a
```

**UPDATE**

```js
insert into db0.user(all columns)
select * from (
    select "apply case for some columns" from db1.user,db2.user
    where "apply your condition" ) as a
```

consider the following facts:
1. In this above query we are doing cross multiplication between db1.user and db2.user by which we get all possible values from these 2 tables

2. If you want to apply condition in "where" clause for email(for example db1.user.email = db2.user.email) then you can write db1.user.email or db2.user.email after "select", because both values are same.
3. If you want to apply >= or <= condition you have to apply "case" after "select".Because you have to fetch any one value from 2 tables

For example you want to fetch lastlogin data, for this condition I have applied case in lastlogin column. By this condition you will get column value from either db1.user or db2.user.

4. conditions in where clause can be written in case form after "select" also.

Please have a look on the UPDATE portion.
And I went for prayer, that is why this late reply.

If it helps mark as right answer.
Thank you

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but my issue is that i need to fetch all columns based on condition db1.user.lastlogin >= db2.user.lastlogin. So one option is that i check this condition for each column but as i have long list of column so is there any way by which i can skip additional checking. If condition is true then fetch all column from db1 else pick from db2

Comment: how many columns do you want to compare ? does your db0.user table consists of 2 columns ? If yes then do you want to insert all columns from db1.user or db2.user into this db0.user ? please clarify this

Comment: please clarify the line: "So one option is that i check this condition for each column but as i have long list of column so is there any way by which i can skip additional checking"

Comment: Means that i have mentioned only 2 columns UserName, Email just for easy handling of data but in actual i have total 15 column which i need to insert based on condition of LastLogin. So should i chcek condition for each column or is there any way by which i can check condition once for each record and pick all columns in one go rather than picking one by one. Is it clear now ?